# GWT RPC Java server with remote Windows authentication

Tags: gwt, authentication, kerberos

I have the following setup with my GWT Client - Server application:

GWT Client -(RPC)- Server - MSSQL db.

The client is running on various platforms & devices (web application, mobile phones etc..). The java server (and web application files) are hosted on Jetty. MSSQL Database is running on a different server on a different domain.

I need to find a way for the user to authenticate on the domain of the MSSQL DB after which I can allow the client to access to rest of the servers services.

I can pass the username & password pair encrypted to the server but how do I continue from there on? I spent a lot of time figuring that out today, but I just got more and more confused. I did manage to check local authentication with Kerberos on the server, but I need to authenticate remotely to a different domain. Is it even possible without setting up service for that on the remote domain, which I'm trying to avoid?

Comment: I don't think there's much good reason for users to authenticate with the DB server, why not just do like every application I've seen and get the user to authenticate in the web server?? You can have different user levels with different privileges, but the web server usually needs only one type of access to the DB server (read/write in certain tables).

Comment: Renato is right, the users do not need access to the DB but the application. Provide a separate login to the databse for the app and you are done. Make sur that your JDBC driver supports Kerberos auth with a keytab.